# Ruby Remove Array in Array when One Item is Nil or ""

Tags: arrays, ruby

In Ruby, I am trying to display items that are in an array of arrays if both items in the array are present. For example:

```rb
nested_array = [["ABC Inc", "This is a test"], 
                ["XYZ Inc", "This is a second test"], 
                ["EFG Inc", ""]]
```

When displaying this array on the front end, I would like to display the first set and second set, but not display the third: `"EFG Inc"`, as it is missing the second item in the array.

The front end currently displays:

**ABC Inc:**
This is a test

**XYZ Inc:**
This is a second test

**EFG Inc:**

Comment: You could write `[["ABC Inc", "This is a test"], ["XYZ Inc", "This is a second test"], ["EFG Inc", ""]].each { |s1,s2| puts "#{s1}: #{s2}" unless s2.empty? }`. This is a pure Ruby question so you should remove the Rails tag.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That’s an answer! Make it so.

Comment: @Franklin, however illogical it might be, I just cannot bring myself to post answers to what are trivial questions for anyone other than a Ruby newbie. This is not to say that it is a trivial question for a newbie; I may have struggled with it myself many moons ago, so I have no objection to the question. Nor would I mind if someone else posted an answer similar to my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby I would use [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-select) to only pick those nested arrays that have all elements being present, like this:

```
nested_array = [["ABC Inc", "This is a test"], ["XYZ Inc", "This is a second test"], ["EFG Inc", ""]]
nested_array.select { |array| array.none?(&:empty?) }
#=> [["ABC Inc", "This is a test"], ["XYZ Inc", "This is a second test"]]
```

See [`Array#none?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-none-3F) and [`String#empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-empty-3F)

In Ruby on Rails, you can also use [`Array#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-all-3F) and [`Object#present?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) which reads nicer and also covers `nil` elements:

```
nested_array = [["ABC Inc", "This is a test"], ["XYZ Inc", "This is a second test"], ["EFG Inc", ""]]
nested_array.select { |array| array.all?(&:present?) }
#=> [["ABC Inc", "This is a test"], ["XYZ Inc", "This is a second test"]]
```